# I am working on highcharts, how to set tool tip when mouser over on title and subtitle

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to add tooltip for title and subtitle for `highcharts`.
Here is my JS Fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9n67zvx/9)

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, you can get started here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v9n67zvx/9/

Comment: Please go thorough my fiddle may you can get idea how to tooltip for title and subtiles, I have gone through the documentation but it is only applicable for series.

Comment: Checkout Custom events module, highcharts doesn't come with support for title/subtitle tooltips. https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events This should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts does not have hooks for title/subtitle events. You need to set events for mouseover/mouseout, build the tooltip and toggle its visibility.

on chart's load

```
var title = document.querySelector('.highcharts-title')
var tooltip = document.createElement('span')
tooltip.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip')
tooltip.innerHTML = title.innerHTML
this.container.appendChild(tooltip)

title.onmouseover = function(e) {
  tooltip.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'
  tooltip.style.top = e.clientY + 'px'
  tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

title.onmouseout = function() {
  tooltip.style.visibility = 'hidden'
}
```

css

```
.tooltip {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ym85u1ja/

The sample applies for the subtitle - you can grab the element with `.highcharts.subtitle` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 title: {
  text: 'example',
  useHTML: true,
  widthAdjust: -400
 },
 subtitle: {
  text: 'Example1',
  useHTML: true ,
   widthAdjust: -400
},
```